# Drawing canvas in Js isnt working, but not any errors in console

Tags: javascript, oop, canvas, drawing

Im trying to make a drawing canvas in object Oriented Js, i had some errors that i fixed, apparently but not one part of my code seems to work (not even the sizing). Here is my js code. 
(I can provide html but i only have a canvas element and clean button)

```
class signature{
    constructor(){
        this.canvas  = document.querySelector('canvas');
        this.bouton = document.querySelector('button');
        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
        this.dessin = false;
    }

    //sizing  
    tailleCanvas(){
        this.canvas.width= 200;
        this.canvas.height= 200;
    }

    //start the drawing
    start (e){
        this.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', ()=>{
            this.dessin = true;
            draw(e);
        });
    };

    //draw
    draw({clientX:x, clientY:y}){
        this.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', ()=>{
            if (!this.dessin) return;

            this.ctx.lineWidth = 3;
            this.ctx.lineCap = 'round';
            this.ctx.strokeStyle = '#171717';

            this.ctx.lineTo(x, y);
            this.ctx.stroke();
            //rendre les lignes moins pixelisé
            this.ctx.beginPath();
            this.ctx.moveTo(x,y);
        })
    };

    //stop drawing
    stop(){
        this.canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', ()=>{
            this.dessin = false;
            this.ctx.beginPath();
        });
    };

    //clean canvas
    bouttonSup(){
        this.bouton.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        this.ctx.clearRect(0,0,this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
        })
    }
};
const signature1 = new signature();
```

Comment: _"but not any errors in console"_ - `this.canvas.width.bind(this)` will definitely throw an error.

Comment: `const signature1 = new signature();` <- here you're instantiating a new instance of signature but you aren't calling it's `start()` function anywhere

Comment: [MDN | Class body and method definitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Class_body_and_method_definitions)

Comment: @obscure Where should i call it ? In the constructor ? Edit: i called under the constructor but in console it says that there a unexpected token ';'

Comment: Yes, either there ( `this.start();` ) or just add `signature1.start();` after `const signature1 = new signature();`

Comment: @obscure I changed it, some errors in console that i need to fix. Will come back to you if fixing those doesnt change anything, thanks for you help !

Comment: No problem @Gobii - glad I could help!